# Python Modulo Complex numbers

Tags: python, operators, complex-numbers

```
def print_numbers_modulo(List,Operator,ModuloNumber):
    CheckIfPrintedNumber=False
    for i in range(0,len(List)):
        if (abs(List[i]),Operator,ModuloNumber):
            print(List[i])
    if (CheckIfPrintedNumber == False):
        print("There are no numbers having modulo",Operator,ModuloNumber)
```

This is my funcion and I call it like this:

```
 print_numbers_modulo(List,'<',10)
```

an the list is defined as:

```
 List=([1+3j,12j,-1j,12+3j,13,12j,12-3j,-45j,-45-5j,0,-323j,-2+3j])
```

why does it print all the numbers not only the one having modulo <10

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work that way. You can use `operator.__xx__` methods instead.

Comment: By the way, you can't really order complex and integer types.

Comment: why do you expect `(abs(List[i]),Operator,ModuloNumber)` to automagically work that way?

Comment: Even if that did work to do the less than, you're still not calculating the modulo anywhere.

Comment: @coldspeed: he/she compares the `abs(..)`. The `abs` of a complex number is a real number that is the 2-norm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
op = {'<': '__lt__', '>': '__gt__', '<=': '__le__', '>=': '__ge__'}

def print_numbers_modulo(List,Operator,ModuloNumber):
    CheckIfPrintedNumber=False
    for i in range(0,len(List)):
        if getattr(abs(List[i]), op[Operator])(ModuloNumber):
            print(List[i])
            CheckIfPrintedNumber = True
    if (CheckIfPrintedNumber == False):
        print("There are no numbers having modulo",Operator,ModuloNumber)
List=([1+3j,12j,-1j,12+3j,13,12j,12-3j,-45j,-45-5j,0,-323j,-2+3j])

print_numbers_modulo(List,'<',10)
```

`op` is a dictionary that "translates" your operator in the corresponding magic method of the float class, as a string.
Then, you can use `getattr` to call the method on `abs(List[i])`, with `ModuloNumber` as parameter:

```
getattr(abs(List[i]), op[Operator])(ModuloNumber)
```

If, for example, `Operator = "<"`, this is equivalent to :

```
abs(List[i]).__lt__(ModuloNumber)
```